# ASP GridView bad Performance using Internet Explorer

Tags: asp.net, performance, internet-explorer, gridview

Hey I have a Problem with the Performance of ASP Gridview using Internet Explorer. My table has about 2000 rows and it seems that this are to many for GridView. I have already tryed activating the Paging and even to give the whole GridView in a UpdatePanel.

What's really strange is that the Problem is not the Loading of the Data (the whole table is visible very fast), but the handling of the page. When you whant to click an the TextBoxes in the Header, or even to Highlight some data, IE is doing that with delay about 5 seconds and then freezes with "not working anymore".

The same Site in Firefox works wonderful with no delays. 
You can see part of my Code here:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewHandys" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataSourceID="HandyDataSource" AllowSorting="True"  PageSize="25"
                AllowPaging="true" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" UseAccessibleHeader="True" ViewStateMode="Enabled" 
                OnSorting="onSort" >
<AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
```

Here is an example for a column:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>
     <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%#Eval"Kostenstelle")%>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
<HeaderTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Kostenstelle" 
    CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="Kostenstelle" ForeColor="White">
    </asp:LinkButton><br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearchKostenstelle" runat="server" Text="" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="onFilter" CssClass="grid_tb"></asp:TextBox>
</HeaderTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

and how the Data is bound:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="HandyDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:GanzNeuConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="Select * from Table1 "></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: right click your page, look at the viewstate, thousands of rows are generally too many with a server based control, because it needs to store the 'states' between server round trips, think about using javascript on the cliet with AJAX and a webservice serving data only, even then 2000 is a lot of records depending on the power of the client machine / network connectio etc...

Comment: only for testing I reduced the number of lines to 15 and nothing happened, I have the same Performance Problem. Something went terrible wrong here... In the code behind there is nothing left then comments and I have not used JavaScript at all. Sure it has to do something with the viewstate?

Comment: if you have a performane problem and there's not data you need to work backwards and find the cause first, then try it with the data

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it was a Problem of VisualStudio. Opening another IE with the same Link works wonderful and also the Version on the productive server works without any Problems.